# How can I configure Jenkins pull request builder to run tests on Github dependabot PRs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, github

Our Github project repository is configured to receive security PRs from dependabot, and we get them periodically.

We are using Jenkins with Build Triggers so that when a user comments /test in a PR comment, it triggers a test.

However, on dependabot PRs, that ends up doing nothing.

I added "dependabot" to the jenkins whitelist, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Using Jenkins 2.249.1